# passing text/string in url of telegram bot by python

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I want to pick a data from a website and need to send on telegram bot as message
i'm able to send a text message "Hello" on telegram bot by `pyhton` code:

```
r = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXtokenXXXX/sendMessage?chat_id=XXXXXXXX&text=hello)
```

but I want to pass a variable string(`str1` in the code) instead of static text message. Hence what is the change I need to do?

My code is:

```
import requests
response1 = requests.get('https://coindelta.com/api/v1/public/getticker/')
lines = []
for line in response1.text:
    lines.append(line)
str1 = ''.join(lines)
r = requests.get('https://api.telegram.org/botXXXXtokenXXXX/sendMessage?chat_id=XXXXXXXX&text=hello)
```

Comment: Consider reading a Python introductory tutorial which will cover string formatting

Comment: Why don't you use [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) instead of using raw requests?

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts and improvements:

1. It's more clear and readable to use `POST` to send bot messages
2. Since you receive a JSON from https://coindelta.com, you can use `json()` to iterate over data in response.
3. You can use list comprehension to format data from response.
4. I've put a `\n` delimiter to `str1`. I think it's more readable.

Working example:

```
import requests

USER_ID = 12345678900000  # this is your chat_id: int
BOT_TOKEN = 'botXXXXtokenXXXX'  # your bot token: str 

# getting data from coindelta.com
r = requests.get('https://coindelta.com/api/v1/public/getticker/')
str1 = '\n'.join([str(line) for line in r.json()])  # desired formatted string

# sending message to user
url = 'https://api.telegram.org/{}/sendMessage'.format(BOT_TOKEN)
post_data = {"chat_id": USER_ID, "text": str1}
tg_req = requests.post(url, data=post_data)
```

Comment: Thank you! Solved issue I was having sending multiple lines of text to a telegram bot.